# Tire rotation to fix low tire pressure?

Tags: honda, tires, civic

I took my 2010 Civic to the mechanic. He indicated that the tire pressure is low, and suggested rotating my tires as a fix.

I thought tire pressure is already pre-specified and should be at a specific value (eg. 32PSI, which is what's indicated inside the front door). Assuming they do re-pump it to the target pressure:

- Is there anything specific about low tire pressure that necessitates rotating it?
- Since Civics have a low-tire-pressure indicator, is this something that can only be done at a mechanic?

NB: this mechanic is known for recommending changes that may not be necessary, and pressuring buyers into saying "yes."

Comment: I don't know which years this covers with Honda TPMS, but you may want to [look at this video](http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/2014/Accord-Coupe/features/Tire-Pressure-Monitoring-System-%28TPMS%29/4). It left me wondering why Honda has to make things so difficult sometimes, lol.

Comment: @Paulster2 that's for accords (not civics), and 2011-2015 are the 9th generation -- 2006-2010 are the 8th generation, so I doubt if it applies.

Comment: I didn't know which years applied to what, but thought I'd throw it out there. As per your question, it doesn't make any sense to me rotating tires to fix a low pressure issue.

Comment: @Paulster2 please use answers to answer questions (instead of comments).

Comment: The problem is, I don't have an answer for you. I have guesses, but no answers, thus the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotating your tyres won't fix a low pressure, you have to pump them up for that! I can't see any reason why rotating them would help with a persistent pressure loss (slow puncture) either - the only fix for that is to remove the culprit tyre, clean the rim and re-mount it.

It might, however, be that they are due for rotation anyway?

If your mechanic is known for pressuring customers into paying for unnecessary changes, I'd suggest getting a new, more trustworthy, mechanic...

Answer (score 0):

Stop going to that mechanic IMMEDIATELY. He's telling half-truths (which is how communists come to power).

Tyre rotation has nothing to do with tyre pressures. Your tyres lose pressure because they either have a slow leak, or you like driving fast over bumps. Rotating them will only make the problem appear on another wheel.

You can reinflate your tyres while you're filling up at a gas station.

Comment: Hitler?  Seriously?  Perhaps an edit to remove the parenthetical?

Comment: communists? more like all politicians.

Comment: All politicians are communists.